# How to convey "opening a can of worms" in Spanish?

Tags: traducción, coloquialismos, solicitud-de-modismo

The idiomatic expression "to open a can of worms" means to try to solve a problem, only to create more problems out of it or to get into a lot of trouble as a consequence of trying to fix this problem in the first place.

From [How Did the Term "Open a Can of Worms" Originate?](http://mentalfloss.com/article/31039/how-did-term-open-can-worms-originate)

> Metaphorically speaking, to open a can of worms is **to examine or attempt to solve some problem, only to inadvertently complicate it and create even more trouble**. Literally speaking, opening a can of worms, as most fishermen can attest, can also mean more trouble than you bargained for.

And in [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/can_of_worms)

> (idiomatic) A complex, troublesome situation arising when **a decision or action produces considerable subsequent problems**.
>
> - If someone gets a promotion that might not be deserved, it could open up a whole can of worms with the other employees.
>
> (idiomatic) A troublesome situation; an issue whose resolution is difficult or contentious but not necessarily complex.
>
> - Questioning the decision would definitely open a can of worms.

Is there a equivalent in Spanish for this idiom apart from referring to Pandora's box? Something that means "to create a complicated situation in which doing something to correct a problem leads to many more problems".

Comment: ¿"Abrir la caja de los truenos" valdría?

Comment: Por qué no? Es simplemente una corrupción de la caja de Pandora o tiene otro origen? Es posible documentar un poco su uso u origen? El original viene a ser "abrir la caja de gusanos", pero viene del uso literal de abrir algo que tiene seres escurridizos dentro. "Caja de truenos" no es muy literal, pero si su uso está extendido y la gente lo entiende bien, no sé porqué no habría de ser una respuesta válida. El resto de usuarios ya lo respaldarán mediante los votos.

Comment: No estoy familiarizado con la expresión inglesa, pero se me ocurre _Salir el tiro por la culata_. ¿Tiene el mismo sentido?

Comment: @fedorqui la idea es parecida, sí, aunque no es precisamente el mismo sentido.

Comment: I don't think "opening a can of worms" creates a new problem or makes a problem more complicated.  What it does is make a previously contained problem uncontained and therefore harder to ignore.

Comment: Este enlace tiene un montón de ejemplos, con traducciones.  Abrir a caja de Pandora es frecuente.  https://www.linguee.com/english-spanish/search?query=open+up+a+can+of+worms

Answer (score 4):

On thing that comes to my mind resembling the counterproductive nature of an outcome (with the opposite result achieved to one's porpoise) is the idiom:

> **Ir por lana y salir trasquilado** (see it [here](https://refranenmano.blogspot.com/2016/05/ir-por-lana-y-salir-trasquilado.html))

Another one that is connected to "opening a can of worms", for the undesired troubles that are brought to oneself, is

> **Meterse en camisa de once varas**.  (as explained [here])[2](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meterse_en_camisa_de_once_varas)

Say for someone objecting his director's resolution, which *opened a can of worms* for himself

> *Al objetar la decisión del directór, 'se metió en camisa de once varas'*

Also, in a similar sense, to unwillingly find oneself in a worse off situation, despite how good intentions might existed , there is the saying

> ***Meter(se) en un brete*** {[source](http://www.fraseshechas.net/poner-en-un-brete/#more-736) [explanation](https://historiasdelahistoria.com/2014/03/14/poner-en-un-brete))
>
> For example*:
> *"El ascenso de cargo lo puso en un brete en la oficina, porque varios de sus compañeros desaprobaron lo que consideraban una promoción laboral injusta"*

Comment: +1, aunque este lo suelo usar en otro contexto (por ejemplo, si le haces un comentario mordaz a alguien en plan broma y te contesta con un comentario todavía mejor. Es como ir buscando pelea y tener que volverte con el rabo entre las piernas). No se me había ocurrido usarlo en este contexto. Funciona bien.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you don't like or don't find it useful to say "abrir la caja de Pandora", which seems to render the meaning quite closely.

Some additional suggestions:

- salirle a alguien el tiro por la culata ([Source](https://books.google.com.ar/books?id=sZ3SjYo5BnsC&pg=PA74&lpg=PA74&dq=%22salirle%20el%20tiro%20por%20la%20culata%22&source=bl&ots=Ufontgnstl&sig=ACfU3U04x2f4TphfQPO1QuSr4tJigF2yKg&hl=es-419&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiUutX9hbPlAhVuGrkGHU1QBSo4ChDoATAAegQICRAB#v=onepage&q=%22salirle%20el%20tiro%20por%20la%20culata%22&f=false))

> [image: tiro por la culata]

The only problem here is that the action was considered negative from the beginning. There is, on the part of the speaker, a hint of justice having been done.

This might be more accurate:

- meterse en un berenjenal ([Source](https://es.wikiquote.org/wiki/Proverbios_argentinos#cite_ref-bermet_637-0))

> «Meterse en un berenjenal.»
>   Nota: Crear problemas o dificultades a alguien o a uno mismo.

Comment: "Meterse en un berenjenal" conserva mejor el sentido original que "salirle el tiro por la culata". Este último es "te sale lo que intentabas del revés, con consecuencias negativas para ti". El primero tiene más de "intentas resolver un problema y te metes en un buen follón". Ambos tienen consecuencias negativas para el que lo intenta, pero creo que "meterse en un berenjenal" conlleva que los problemas generados son muchos y no necesariamente lo opuesto a lo que se intentaba, por lo que cuadra mejor.

Comment: Por cierto [¿De dónde surge la expresión ‘meterse en un berenjenal’?](https://blogs.20minutos.es/yaestaellistoquetodolosabe/de-donde-surge-la-expresion-meterse-en-un-berenjenal/): El dicho tiene un origen rural y hace referencia a que las berenjenas son unas plantas espinosas que al crecer se vuelven molestas, por los arañazos y pinchazos que te puedes llevar. Por este motivo, si te metes en un berenjenal sin tener el debido cuidado, puedes salir lleno de rasguño

Comment: En el dialecto argentino el equivalente de esto, de "complicarse la vida con algo" es ***meterse en un quilombo*** 
Ver https://elpais.com/cultura/2017/05/11/actualidad/1494529191_436778.html

Como en este ejemplo en el que Juan Saturnian habla de las dificultades de escribir una novela http://www.revistasudestada.com.ar/articulo/1206/escribir-una-novela-es-meterse-en-un-quilombo/

Comment: Lo del berenjenal está en linea con la expresión *revolver el avispero*, o sea ir en la dirección segura de los problemas

Comment: @user2325442 El escritor es Juan Sasturian. Ref. "revolver el avispero", me parece que tiene otra connotación, relacionada con agitar los ánimos.

Comment: @user2325442 Pues "revolver el avispero" se puede merecer su propia entrada como respuesta.

Comment: @user2325442 Quise decir Sasturain.